# Como gravar o HTML completo de um formulário no MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando gravar o HTML completo de um formulário. Uma vez que tenho um sistema em que cada usuário pode ter sua forma individual de pagamento, o que exige que cada um grave o código do botão de compra por exemplo, do PagSeguro.

O que gera este erro quando tento gravar no MYSQL por meio de um formulário no administrativo que desenvolvi para gravar estes códigos de pagamentos:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds  
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'post' 
action='https://www.meu.url/PagamentoSimples.do'>
```

Já tentei utilizar diversos códigos como:

```
$clientepagseguro = strip_tags($_POST['clientepagseguro']);
```

Nada deu certo.

O HTML:

```
<form method='post' action='https://www.meu.url/PagamentoSimples.do'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id_carteira' value='suporte@mail.foo'/>
    <input type='hidden' name='valor' value='4000'/>
    <input type='hidden' name='nome' value='Site Lucrativo'/>
    <input type='image' name='submit' src='https://static.moip.com.br/imgs/buttons/bt_pagar_c01_e04.png' alt='Pagar' border='0' />
</form>
```

O que faço para solucionar?

Comment: @FleuquerLima campo do tipo TEXT

Answer (score 0):

## O problema

Você tem que escapar os dados vindos do formulário, isso em qualquer dado que vá para o banco. Se você não está fazendo isso, além do problema apresentado, provavelmente seu sistema está vulnerável a ataques de SQL Injection.

O que acontece é que nos dados enviados pelo usuário, se tratando de um código HTML, ele terá provavelmente, aspas simples e essas aspas simples, quando não escapadas, acabam danificando a query.

```
INSERT INTO `pagamento` (`btn_html`) VALUES ('Código HTML');
```

Quando você adiciona um código HTML, daria problema, veja abaixo (isso se possuir aspas simples):

```
INSERT INTO `pagamento` (`btn_html`) VALUES ('<a href='#'>Meu botão</a>');
```

Veja no exemplo acima que temos um conflito. As aspas referentes ao link acabam por bugar a query e o MySQL irá entender que está sendo passado 2 valores distintos: o valor `<a href=` e o valor `>Meu botão</a>`.

Isso por si só já daria problema porque você só especificou uma coluna, além disso, tem o caractere `#` "solto" que também daria problema.

## Soluções

Isso vai depender de como está fazendo a conexão com o banco, se é usando MySQLi, ou PDO.

No caso do MySQLi, você pode resolver assim

```
$string = "Caixa d'água";
$stringPronta = mysql_real_escape_string($string, $conexao);

//$stringPronta irá ficar assim: Caixa d\'água
```

Perceba que o caractere de aspa foi escapado com uma barra invertida, da mesma forma que fazemos pra escapar valores no PHP. Lembre-se que a variável $conexao é referente ao seu link de conexão criado anteriormente.

Embora isso resolva o problema, algumas pessoas dizem que esse método não é 100% seguro contra SQL Injections, portanto, vale dar uma pesquisada ou optar por usar PDO.

Para resolver o problema com PDO, faça

```
$inserirBtn = $conexao->prepare("INSERT INTO `pagamento` (`btn_html`) VALUES (:btn_html)");
$inserirBtn->bindValue(':btn_html', $string);
$inserirBtn->execute();
```

Perceba que no caso do PDO, é muito mais simples porque ele escapa os dados "nativamente" antes de executar a query no servidor de banco de dados.